# Where is mdm-config.xml? It is not on repositories/conf/

Tags: wso2

I have installed and running the emm service. I'm issuing the certificates and following the steps provided into the tutorial ( https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM100/Generating+an+APNS+Certificate )
but I'm not able to find the mdm-conf.xml to modify the ios apn configuration.

What I'm missing? Do I have to install some module first to have the MDM capabilities?

Btw, I found an script made by duchiland to configure out everything that, when I found the mdm-config.xml file will be so helpful. https://gist.github.com/dulichan/8573441 :)

Thank you in advance.
Arturo.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake. I was following the 1.0.0 documentation instead of the 1.1.0 :DDD

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110